# Градиент на тексте + плавная смена градиента (SVG)

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg

В общем есть прямоугольник с контуром, прозрачным фоном и текстом внутри.
Выглядит он вот так:

```html
<svg width="130" height="40">
  <linearGradient id="logo_gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f4523d"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#438fcb"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="126" height="36" fill="transparent" stroke="url(#logo_gradient)" stroke-width="2" />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0">Текст</text>
</svg>
```

1. Как добавить градиент к текст
2. Как сделать плавный "перелив" градиента при наведение (допустим с `45deg` на `135deg`)
   2.1. Какие способы есть для эффекта при наведение (`css`или`jq`, например)

Comment: Это можно сделать не учитывая `CSS` & `JS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можете использовать атрибут fill, так же как это делали для рамки

```css
.button {
  filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.button:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
 <svg class="button" width="130" height="40">
      <linearGradient id="logo_gradient" gradientTransform="rotate(45)">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f4523d"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#438fcb"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <rect x="2" y="2" width="126" height="36" fill="transparent" stroke="url(#logo_gradient)" stroke-width="2" />
      <text fill="url(#logo_gradient)" x="50%" y="50%" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em">Текст</text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: на stackoveflow часто обсуждали что hover на SVG работает ни везде, автор очевидно не проверял Ваш пример в Лисе или в других браузерах...в общем не кроссбраузерно

Comment: на текущий момент это работает в Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari,  единственная проблема в Edge - там не работает плавность анимации

Comment: да я проверил..действительно работает ! извеняюсь .... но единственно в файере тектст мыльный ...очень плохо видно